# Multiple select issue with a HABTM relationship using Rails 4

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

Although the code seems to be right, when I try to send the form, the values of the multiple select aren't being sent.

If I just remove the multiple option, everything works as expected considering just one value, but it's important to store more than one tag per transaction.

**Model**

*Transaction.rb*

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
```

*Tag.rb*

```
class tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :transactions
```

**View**

```
<%= form.collection_select :tag_ids, @tags, :id, :name, {}, 
    {:multiple => true} %>
```

*Result:*

```
<select id="transaction_tag_ids" multiple="multiple" name="transaction[tag_ids][]">  
    <option value="1">..</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Be sure what you properly allow received params for mass assignment.

You said that the one param works, so I assume what you have somewhere in your controller something like:

```
params.require(:transaction).permit(:name, :tag_ids)
```

So you need allow to receive an array:

```
params.require(:transaction).permit(:name, :tag_ids => [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using

```
{:health_unit_ids => []}
```

Rails 4 no accepted without *{}*